# Flex: How to call a function everytime a pop-up is clicked

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, flash-builder

I am trying to automatically focus on a textarea box everytime the link to the pop-up (which the textarea box is contained in) is clicked. I tried doing so with creationComplete but only works once. It doesn't work with initialize either.

```
<s:SkinnablePopUpContainer xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" backgroundAlpha="0" contentBackgroundAlpha="0"
                       width="100%" height="100%"
                       xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" xmlns:scripts="scripts.*"
                       creationComplete="notesTextArea.setFocus();">
```

Answer (score 0):

The only way I solve this was setting the focus after showing the Popup. Example:

```
var aboutWindow:About = new About();
PopUpManager.addPopUp(aboutWindow,this);
PopUpManager.centerPopUp(aboutWindow);
aboutWindow.myTextArea.setFocus();
```

It works fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

While the answer from @gustyaquino is a good suggestion, I believe there is a slightly cleaner solution that is more tailored to the [SkinnablePopUpContainer](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/SkinnablePopUpContainer.html) class that you're using.

`SkinnablePopUpContainer` has an [open()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/SkinnablePopUpContainer.html#open%28%29) method that is normally used to show the pop up. Per the documentation, the `open()` method opens the pop up (using the `PopUpManager`, like in @gustyaquino's code), but it also plays a transition effect, and finally it dispatches a `FlexEvent.OPEN` event.

Also, `SkinnablePopUpContainer` is created once and re-used. This is why your "creationComplete" and "initialize" event solutions only work the first time (when the object is actually created). Notice in @gustyaquino's solution a new pop up is being made each time. This was how we rolled before the `SkinnablePopUpContainer` class existed.

In the example below, I use the "open" event to detect when the pop up is opened and set the focus there. I believe this is slightly cleaner way to do it (re-use the pop up and putting the code to focus the `TextInput` inside the pop up class).

Application MXML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
               xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"
               xmlns:local="*"
               width="100%" height="100%">

    <fx:Declarations>
        <local:MyPopUp id="poppy" />
    </fx:Declarations>

    <s:Button label="Open pop up" click="poppy.open(this)" />

</s:Application>
```

PopUp MXML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:SkinnablePopUpContainer xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
                           xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
                           xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"
                           width="300" height="300"
                           backgroundColor="#c0c0c0"
                           open="onPopUpOpened()">

    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.managers.PopUpManager;

            override public function updatePopUpPosition():void
            {
                PopUpManager.centerPopUp(this);
                // this doesn't work here
                //myInput.setFocus();
            }

            private function onPopUpOpened():void
            {
                myInput.setFocus();
            }

        ]]>
    </fx:Script>

    <s:layout>
        <s:VerticalLayout paddingLeft="10" paddingRight="10" paddingTop="10"/>
    </s:layout>

    <s:TextInput id="myInput" width="100%"  />
    <s:Button label="Close" click="close()"/>
</s:SkinnablePopUpContainer>
```